"Sign Up" and "Sign In" with Google API in Flask
I'm trying to program a login system in Python with Flask using the Google API. It works. However, when the user is already registered and tries to log in for the second time, after choosing the email, the system continues to request access permissions again instead of just allowing the user to enter. I believe that the user would be a little uncomfortable reading "Make sure you trust this app" every time he tries to log in, whereas in any other app, just choose the email and access is granted without having to authorize again...
Screenshot
My source code is this below:
import os
import pathlib

import requests
from flask import Flask, session, abort, redirect, request, render_template
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow
from pip._vendor import cachecontrol
import google.auth.transport.requests

from database.db import PostgreSQLConnection
from object.user import UserObject
from model.user import UserModel

db = PostgreSQLConnection()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "123"

os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "123"
client_secrets_file = os.path.join(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent, "client_secret.json")

flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    client_secrets_file=client_secrets_file,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            "openid"],
    redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback"
)


def login_is_required(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if "google_id" not in session:
            return abort(401)  # Authorization required
        else:
            return function()

    return wrapper


@app.route("/login")
def login():
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url()
    session["state"] = state
    return redirect(authorization_url)


@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=request.url)

    if not session["state"] == request.args["state"]:
        abort(500)  # State does not match!

    credentials = flow.credentials
    request_session = requests.session()
    cached_session = cachecontrol.CacheControl(request_session)
    token_request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request(session=cached_session)

    id_info = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(
        id_token=credentials._id_token,
        request=token_request,
        audience=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    )

    session["google_id"] = id_info.get("sub")
    session["email"] = id_info.get("email")
    session["given_name"] = id_info.get("given_name")
    session["family_name"] = id_info.get("family_name")

    if UserModel.get_user(db, session["google_id"]):
        print('Usuário:', session["email"])
    else:
        print('Usuário novo:', session["email"])
        user = UserObject(session["google_id"], session["email"], session["given_name"], session["family_name"])
        UserModel.add_new_user(db, user)

    return redirect("/home")


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect("/")


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route("/home")
@login_is_required
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', name=session['given_name'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

It's my first time programming, forgive me for any poorly written code...
I searched all over Google but didn't find the solution.
